# Tool for simulating ASM code on windows

Tags: assembly, nasm, qemu

I'm currently using NASM to compile the code but there is not tool to simulate the code. Please suggest any easy to use tool for simulation.

Thanks.

Comment: As someone already tagged it, you need `qemu`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 for qemu. [bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) also supports windows.